C# console app connect to Snowflake using RSA key in file
I'm trying to connect to Snowflakes from a .NET Console application with an RSA key.
It works fine if I try with a username and password:
account=ACCOUNTNAME;user=test; password=Test123;db=PROD_ANALYTICS;

However, the connection with the RSA key does not work:
account=ACCOUNTNAME;user=test;privateKey=values of the key;db=PROD_ANALYTICS;authenticator=snowflake;

I tried with the generated der file as well.
I'm getting the following error :

Error: Required property PASSWORD is not provided. SqlState: , VendorCode: 270006

